# How does angular handle comparison during default change detection, when it comes to objects or array of objects?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

Given this statement ([source](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/)) :

> [...] **How does the default change detection mechanism work**? This method
> might look strange at first, with all the strangely named variables.
> But by digging deeper into it, we notice that it's doing something
> very simple: **for each expression used in the template, it's comparing
> the current value of the property used in the expression with the
> previous value of that property.** If the property value before and
> after is different, it will set isChanged to true, and that's it! Well almost, it's comparing values by using a method called
> looseNotIdentical(), which is really just a === comparison with special logic for the NaN case ([see here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/885f1af509eb7d9ee049349a2fe5565282fbfefb/packages/core/src/util/comparison.ts)).

I have read many similar articles, and I understand how comparison is done when it's a simple type, but I can't figure out how it is done when the property is an object or an array of objects.

Looking at the [implementation code from angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/885f1af509eb7d9ee049349a2fe5565282fbfefb/packages/core/src/util/comparison.ts), I found out that it does more than just comparing the values, depending on the type of the property.

**So my question is** : During detection change, how does angular handle comparisons by values when the property's type is an object or an array of objects, given that the ChangeDetectionStrategy is Default (and not Push) ?

*For example and in case of arrays of objects, does it iterate over the objects and compare the references ?*

Comment: `onChanges` only detects changes to references - not values. If you alter an array of objects that is an input, that will **not** be picked up in `ngOnChanges()` unless you pass a new reference for the array

Answer (score 0):

The equality operator `===` works just fine on objects (arrays are objects as well). There's no difference in how these are handled. When you initialize an object, it gets an identity, so an object is only equal to itself.

Example:

```js
const obj1 = {};
const obj2 = {};

console.log("obj1 === obj2",obj1 === obj2) // false, two different objects
console.log("obj1 === obj1",obj1 === obj1) // true, same object

const arr1 = [];
const arr2 = [];

console.log("arr1 === arr2",arr1 === arr2) // false, two different arrays
console.log("arr1 === arr1",arr1 === arr1) // true, same array
```

Nowadays Angular uses `Object.is` instead of `looseNotIdentical()` which has the same behaviour: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/core/src/util/comparison.ts#L22

If you use a directive like `ngFor` to iterate an array, then the change detector will check the identity of each entry according to the `trackByFn` provided. They also track index changes if an item moved from one place to another. The source for that is here: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_iterable_differ.ts